# Where are the OpenCV propId values located?

Tags: c++, opencv

These are the values that set different properties of the VideoCapture class. I have already included opencv2/opencv.hpp, but when I try to run

```
VideoCapture::set(CV_CAP_PROP_FPS, 20);
```

As seen in [this documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/highgui/doc/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html?highlight=fps#VideoWriter::VideoWriter(const%20string&%20filename,%20int%20fourcc,%20double%20fps,%20Size%20frameSize,%20bool%20isColor)):

It gives me an error saying that CV_CAP_PROP_FPS is undefined. Where are the PropID values located?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you will need to include the [opencv2/videoio/videoio_c.h](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/blob/master/modules/videoio/include/opencv2/videoio/videoio_c.h#L145) file too. (It is unfortunate it was not mentioned in the docs.)